# How to loop and create an Outlook message body

Tags: vba, outlook, office-automation

I am trying to loop a list from a sheet into a Outlook Body, but I just loops through until the end and show the last one...

Any ideas?

```html
Sub SendEmail()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("PrestageData")
strUsed = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Source As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

EmailItem.To = frmForm.txtCollector.Value & "mail.dk"
'EmailItem.CC = "hello@gmail.com"
'EmailItem.BCC = "hhhh@gmail.com"
EmailItem.Subject = "Din FAP er klar til afhentning"

For i = 2 To strUsed

    If ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "KLAR" Then
        strReady = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hej," & frmForm.txtCollector.Value & "<br><br>" & "Følgende FAP er klar: " & strReady
        'Source = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        'EmailItem.Attachments.Add Source
    End If

Next

EmailItem.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: The line `EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Some text"` overwrites the previous text in  `EmailItem.HTMLBody`, therefore only the last text remains after the loop. Replace with `EmailItem.HTMLBody = EmailItem.HTMLBody + "Some text"` to concatenate all together.

Comment: YES YES YES... You're right my friend...!

Comment: Ideally, you need to find the closing `body` tag in the HTML markup and append your content before it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an [Exit For](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_exit_for_statement.htm) to leave the loop after the first find:

```
For i = 2 To strUsed    
    If ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "KLAR" Then
        strReady = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hej," & frmForm.txtCollector.Value & "<br><br>" & "Følgende FAP er klar: " & strReady
        Exit For
    End If    
Next
```

In case you want to capture multiple matching entries, you have to extend the body rather than replacing it in full. You could append an extra line per entry.

Comment: Hi Axel, I don't understand; I want to show all of the ones that match...

Comment: It is a bad idea to set `HTMLBod`y property in a loop - build HTML body using a dedicated variable and set `HTMLBody` once after the loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

It seems every time in the loop you overwrite the message body. Instead, you need to append the message body with a content found in the worksheet:

```
EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hej," & frmForm.txtCollector.Value

For i = 2 To strUsed

    If ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "KLAR" Then
        strReady = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        EmailItem.HTMLBody = EmailItem.HTMLBody & "<br><br>" & "Følgende FAP er klar: " & strReady
        'Source = ThisWorkbook.FullName
        'EmailItem.Attachments.Add Source
    End If

Next
```

But I'd suggest playing a well-formed HTML markup in the code and find the closing tag in the `HTMLBody` string and paste your add-in there. For example, you could use the Replace function available in VBA:

```
EmailItem.HTMLBody = Replace(EmailItem.HTMLBody, "</body>", "<br><br>" & "Følgende FAP er klar: " & strReady & "</body>")
```